# Webbrowser control in userform: how to wait for page to initialize

Tags: vba, excel, webbrowser-control

Task: using Excel VBA to navigate to a website, log in and go to an input page.
On that page, sequentially enter a series of values stored in a column in Sheet1.

What I've done so far:
I create a webbrowser control and navigate to the website and stop.
Then click on a button on Sheet1 with the macros that will do the inputting, stored in a module.

What's happening:
The control comes up nicely and navigates to the intended site. (this is the userform code)
Click on the button and it gets the userid and password from the spreadsheet, inputs them, clicks on the login button and all is well.
However, the next statement is:

```
Set inputfield = WebBrowser.objWebBrowser.Document.getElementById("ctl02_ctl03_ddlBus")
```

and inputfield comes up empty.

If I stop execution and step through it, it'll work.
I've tried Application.Wait; For x = 1 to 5000000; On Error Goto/Resume and keep trying, but nothings works.

I've also tried .NavigateComplete, .DocumentCompleted, as well as others, but I get errors saying member is not supported.

I am at my wits end - I'm just so close!! So far, I've spent more time on this that it will ever save, but now it's personal! Thanks for your help.

This is borrowed code from another site that initializes the control.

```
Private Sub UserForm_Initialize()

    Dim a, c As Integer

    With Me
        .StartUpPosition = 0
        .Top = 150
        .Left = -700
    End With

    With Me.objWebBrowser
        .Navigate2 "http://www.schoolbuscity.com/Mapnetweb_47/login.aspx"
        .Visible = True
    End With
End Sub


Private Sub GetSheets()

'this is my code

    Dim inputfield As Object

    Dim SendText As String

    Dim NumberOfRoutes, r, errCount As Integer

    errCount = 0

    NumberOfRoutes = Range("NumberOfRoutes")
    ReDim RouteNumbers(NumberOfRoutes) As String

    For r = 1 To NumberOfRoutes
        RouteNumbers(r) = Cells(r, 1).Value
    Next r

'    Sheets("Sheet1").Select

    Range(Cells(5, 2), Cells(6, 2)).ClearContents ' this indicates success for the chosen cells

    SendText = Range("userid").Value
    Set inputfield = WebBrowser.objWebBrowser.Document.getElementById("Login1_UserName")
    inputfield.Value = SendText

    SendText = Range("password").Value
    Set inputfield = WebBrowser.objWebBrowser.Document.getElementById("Login1_Password")
    inputfield.Value = SendText

    Set inputfield = WebBrowser.objWebBrowser.Document.getElementById("Login1_Login")
    Application.Wait (Now + TimeValue("0:00:01"))
    inputfield.Click

    Application.Wait (Now + TimeValue("0:00:01")) ' I've tried waiting for up to 10 seconds

    Set inputfield = Nothing

On Error GoTo TryAgain

    For r = 5 To 6 'NumberOfRoutes ' just want to use 2 loops for testing

' this is where is fails, I believe, because the page is not initialized

' but if waiting is not the answer, then what is?

        Set inputfield = WebBrowser.objWebBrowser.Document.getElementById("ctl02_ctl03_ddlBus")
        inputfield.Value = RouteNumbers(r)

        Set inputfield = WebBrowser.objWebBrowser.Document.getElementById("ctl02_ctl03_btnGo")
        inputfield.Click

        Application.Wait (Now + TimeValue("0:00:01"))
        Cells(r, 2).Value = "Sent"

'        WebBrowser.objWebBrowser.Document.Print

        WebBrowser.objWebBrowser.GoBack
    Next r

GoTo EndIt

TryAgain:

    Set inputfield = Nothing

    Set inputfield = WebBrowser.objWebBrowser.Document.getElementById("ctl02_ctl03_ddlBus")

    errCount = errCount + 1

    If errCount > 5 Then GoTo EndIt

    Resume

EndIt:

If errCount > 0 Then

MsgBox "errCount= " + CStr(errCount)

Else

MsgBox "Did it"

End If

End Sub
```

Comment: This seems like a strange use-case for Excel-VBA; are you sure this is the right tool for the job? (I'd try to help, but I'm not familiar with VBA-web interaction.)

Comment: If you are sure that the document complete event is firing before you look for the input field then does the website have frames or other elements in the main document that are updating async?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is how to waitbin vbscript.

```
     Set ie = CreateObject("InternetExplorer.Application") 
     ie.Visible = 0
     'must navigate to a local file to avoid security prompts
     ie.Navigate2 "C:\Users\User\Desktop\Filter.html"
     Do 
         wscript.sleep 100
     Loop until ie.document.readystate = "complete"
```

Answer (score 0):

examples in VBA:

```
Private Sub UserForm_Initialize()
Set ie = Me.WebBrowser1
ie.Navigate2 "about:blank"
Do Until ie.ReadyState = READYSTATE_COMPLETE
DoEvents
Loop
Set ie = Nothing
End Sub
Private Sub Conectar_Click()
Dim ie As Object
Set ie = Me.WebBrowser1
ie.Navigate2 "http://www.mytest.com"
Do Until ie.ReadyState = READYSTATE_COMPLETE
  DoEvents
Loop
'different alternatives
'Dim inputfield As Object
'Set inputfield = ie.Document.getElementById("Login_tbLogin")
'inputfield.Value = "mylogin"
'Set inputfield = Nothing
'ie.Document.getElementById("Login_tbLogin").Value = "mylogin"
'ie.Document.All("Login_tbLogin").Focus
'ie.Document.All("Login_tbLogin").Value = "mylogin"
ie.Document.All.Item("Login_tbLogin").Value = "mylogin"
Set ie = Nothing
End Sub
```

Comment: Please elaborate your answers.